# Formula to get mean of (n-6) smallest values out of n unsorted values in a row

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, mean

How do I calculate the mean of (n-(ceiling(n*.05))) smallest values out of n unsorted values in a row, using an Excel formula?

I am trying to get the mean of the values in the range removing the largest 5% values which can be considered as spikes. I do not want to pre-sort the row as I want to preserve the order of values.

For example: if the range of values is in D2:Z2, then i need the formula in C2 to return the mean of the (23-(ceiling(23*.05))) = 21 smallest values in the range.

I was looking at `SUMIFS` but  couldn't get it to work with a cell address in the criteria value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This, entered as an array formula with Shift-Ctrl-Enter, works:

```
=SUM(B1:P1*IF(RANK.EQ(B1:P1,$B$1:$P$1)>6,1))/SUM(IF(RANK.EQ(B1:P1,$B$1:$P$1)>6,1))
```

assuming you have n=15 values in range `B1:P1` and you want the mean of the (n-6)=9 smallest values as indicated in your question title.

If you want the `n-(ceiling(n*.05))` smallest values, then just replace the 6 with `CEILING.PRECISE(COUNT($B1:$P1)*0.05)` like this:

```
=SUM(B1:P1*IF(RANK.EQ(B1:P1,$B$1:$P$1)>CEILING.PRECISE(COUNT($B1:$P1)*0.05),1)) 
 /SUM(IF(RANK.EQ(B1:P1,$B$1:$P$1)>CEILING.PRECISE(COUNT($B1:$P1)*0.05),1))
```

Proof and explanation showing intermediate calcs:

[image]

Comment: The formula didnot work in excel. Issues with the syntax used for RANK.EQ. Can you explain your formula better?

Comment: Googled up Array functions in Excel. Now got it to work. Good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Used a simpler hardcoded adhoc solution.
=(SUM(I2:KV2)-SUM(LARGE(I2:KV2,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})))/(COUNT(I2:KV2)-7)